# cannot be resolved to a variable eclipse main class

Tags: java

I am fairly new at this and have been looking for a solution on Internet for two days, yet, I could not find any.

This is the class that I identified and initialized variables.

```
 package HelloWorld;

    import java.awt.*;


    public class Car {

        double averageMilesPerGallon;
        String licensePlate;
        Color paintColor;
        boolean areTaillightsWorking;


        public Car(double inputAverageMPG, 
                    String inputLicensePlate, 
                    Color inputPaintColor, 
                    boolean inputAreTaillightsWorking) {

            this.averageMilesPerGallon = inputAverageMPG;
            this.licensePlate = inputLicensePlate;
            this.paintColor = inputPaintColor;
            this.areTaillightsWorking = inputAreTaillightsWorking;  
        }



    }
```

Then, I wanted use these variables in my main class; however, it did not work. I received an error that was saying; "inputAverageMPG cannot be resolved to a variable" and "inputLicensePlate cannot be resolved to a variable." Please refer below to see the main class wherein I received the error.

```
package HelloWorld;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("yes");



        Car myCar = new Car(inputAverageMPG = 25.5, inputLicensePlate "12HTHF");




        }


    }
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing Java syntax with Python ... or something.  Java doesn't support "paramName = value" syntax in a call.  Please refer to your lecture notes / tutorial / textbook on how to pass parameters in a method or constructor call.

Comment: So when you attempt to do that in Java, the compiler interprets `name = value` as an assignment expression and looks for a variable called `name` ... which doesn't exist in your example.  (Just as well.  If it did exist, the resulting mess wold be horrible to diagnose!)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Car myCar = new Car(25.5,"12HTHF");
```

or create variables first before you use

```
package HelloWorld;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("yes");



    Car myCar = new Car(25.5,"12HTHF");




    }


}



enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the various `inputEtc =` calls in your constructor use inside the Main class, you do not have to do this to specify parameters. An example:

```
//25.5 MPG Car
Car myCar = new Car(25.5, /* other input parameters */);
```

If you're at this point and were stuck for this long, I would recommend [Oracle's Official Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Answer (score -2):

You need to create theses variables before use them.
At first sight : 
Append this lines before creation of myCar object

```
`double inputAverageMPG=25.5;
 String inputLicencePlate=12HTHF"`
```

Comment: You have misunderstood the cause of OP's confusion.  This doesn't solve his problem.